# Apache redirect including "or" syntax

Tags: php, apache, redirect

My problem is the following:

I want to redirect visitors on my website from other pages than `page1.php` and `page2.php`. To make that clear let me give you an example:

If someone visits `example.com/page1.php` or `example.com/page2.php` I want the server to serve exactly that site, but in case any other site is requested such as `example.com/any-other-page.php` I want to redirect them to `domain2.com/any-other-page.php`.

That redirect needs to be done browser-side because of SSL certificate problems, therefore `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond` and so on are not helpful as they cause certificate problems.

I tried

```
Redirect 301 !/page1.php https://domain2.com/
```

but I had no clue how to add second page. Furthermore that didn't work either.

All redirection should preferably done in the `sites-available/example.com.conf` file. 
I've done tons of googling and messing around but most answers use rewrite, which isn't appropriate for my needs.

### Solution:

After a couple of hours I found the solution:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(?!\/page1.php)(?!\/page2.php)(.*) https://domain2.com/$1
```